# Call parent form's click event from a child form without any code change in the parent form code winform

Tags: c#, winforms, events, parent-child

I am creating extensions on windows forms and we are not allowed to change the base forms code.

Now, I have a Process button on the parent form ParentForm. I want to call child form's method on click event of Process button on ParentForm; which I think is not possible without creating an event. If I will create an event I will have to do the code changed on ParentForm, which I can't do.

So, the otherway I thought is if I could call ParentForm's Process button from ChildForm through reflection. Is it possible or any other way to do so.

P.S: I have access to the object of ParentForm on ChildForm, through that object I can access all the properties and methods of ParentForm, but cann't see events. Methods here mean other methods not event handler's method

Comment: How do you want to indentify that Control? Is `Process` its Name or its Caption (text). Do you know these details beforehand or you have other means to single one out?

Comment: Process is text for the button, I can see its name by finding the controls on the form.

Comment: You could also get each Button methods through reflection, use the method enumeration to fill a `List<MethodInfo>` and `.Invoke()` each method by name, when needed. If you want an example of that, no problem (keeping the perfectly valid answer that @Reza Aghaei already gave you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All controls that you added to the base form using designer, have name. Find the button on the form by name and call its `PerformClick` method. For example:

```
var b = theForm.Controls.Find("button1", true).OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault();
if (b != null)
    b.PerformClick();
```

***Warning:*** If you are forced to perform a click this way to start an operation, it's usually a symptom of a bad design. Usually you should be able to call a public method of that class (or protected if it's in the base class) rather that trying to click on a button.

Comment: Oh yeah, I had started the same. Will let you know once checked

Comment: `theForm` is a placeholder for the form which you find its button.

Comment: Thanks Reza! Accepting this as an answer

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Regarding Warning, event is the only way for me as methods are private and handler too

Comment: It's not your fault as the developer who should use/work on top of the existing design. It's designers' fault or those who say *'you are not allowed to change the base forms'*. If there is a method which you should call it from outside of the form, then it should not be private.

Answer (score 1):

If your Button is public (or internal) you can call its click event by:

```
YourParentForm.YourButton.PerformClick();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Poul !
My problem is it's neither public nor internal (Private). That's why I said  I can't see events from the parent form's object.I also don't have access to the parent form's code.

Comment: You too were correct, +1 for your answer. I was thinking in the wrong direction. I should have checked the controls on the form after checking the methods and properties